# Need help testing promise chains using jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I have a function that looks like the following:

```
const func = () => 
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
    asyncFunc()
      .then(data => 
          axios.post('someAPI', {
          data 
        })  
      )
      .then(response => {
          asyncFunc1(response.data)
          resolve(response.data)
      })
      .catch(err => reject(err)
   );
```

I have read through the documentation of jest and mocking async functions, but it does not seem to cover the scope of this function. Can someone provide some insight into testing functions of this complexity?

EDIT:
Here is the function and current testing:

```
export const refreshAuth = () =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    getRefreshToken()
      .then(refreshJWT =>
        axios.post(`${SomeAPI.auth}/refresh`, {
          refreshJWT
        })
      )
      .then((res: AxiosResponse<JWTData>) => {
        onSignIn(res.data.accessJWT, res.data.refreshJWT);
        resolve(res.data.accessJWT);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error('failed to refresh the access token', err);
        reject(err);
      })
  );



export const onSignIn = (access: string, refresh: string) =>
  Promise.all([
    SecureStore.setItemAsync(REFRESH_KEY, refresh),
    SecureStore.setItemAsync(ACCESS_KEY, access)
  ]);


export const getRefreshToken = () => SecureStore.getItemAsync(REFRESH_KEY);
```

And Testing:

```
describe('OAuth2', () => {
  it('Runs all promise chains within refreshAuth()', async done => {
    const data = {
      data: {
        accessJWT: 'token',
        refreshJWT: 'refresh'
      }
    };

    const getItemAsync = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({ refreshToken: 'refresh' });
    const mockOnSignIn = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({});
    const mockPostAxios = mockedAxios.post.mockResolvedValue(data);
    return OAuth2.refreshAuth().then(() => {
      expect(getItemAsync).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(mockPostAxios).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(mockOnSignIn).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
        data.data.accessJWT,
        data.data.refreshJWT
      );
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you update your question to include the test code so we me see what and how you are testing?

Comment: Added above @DrewReese

Comment: For a single promise, I use "resolves.toBe" from Jest. For chains maybe better use ASINC/AWAIT and wait response for every part of chain.

Comment: @ИльяЛокалин Thanks for that tip, I am more interested in mocking the actual functions, right now it's still calling original refreshAuth() function and not running the mock functions.

Comment: refreshAuth has two antipatterns. It doesn't need `new Promise` because there's already a promise. And it should return a promise in order for it to be chained in tests. It's unclear how you intend to mock functions. It's important where they come from and this isn't shown. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Basically you can mock functions from other modules with jest.mock, and you cannot mock functions defined in the same module they are used.

Comment: @EstusFlask As for the function, I did not write it I was only instructed to test the function. 

As for mocking the functions, how does one go about properly mocking a series of functions? And how do you tell jest to use those mocked functions and not run the original function when running the test?

Comment: Then you have a problem because that it doesn't returns a promise makes it harder to test. That they are called in series doesn't affect anything. Previous comment explains how functions can be mocked. Again, it's important where these functions come from. If they are defined in the same module, you won't be able to mock anything except Axios. Please, provide MCVE, otherwise the question is off-topic because you omitted relevant details. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @EstusFlask I added where the fucntions in the main function come from. For mocking refreshAuth(), would I make a __mock__ file and mock a function that resolves an empty promise?

Comment: refreshAuth is the unit that is tested, it shouldn't be mocked. And you cannot mock other functions because they are defined in the same module, this is not possible in JS. So you need to mock underlying APIs (axios.post and SecureStore.setItemAsync), e.g. `jest.spyOn(SecureStore, 'setItemAsync').mockResolvedValue(mockedJwtToken)`. Use `Once` spy mocks if you need it to mock differently on each call. Hope this helps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221839/discussion-between-jacob-and-estus-flask).